# apache - redirect to https://www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, vhosts

I'm having a bit of trouble with this. Essentially what I'm after is:

1. http://example.com -> https://www.example.com
2. https://example.com -> https://www.example.com

Basically all URLs should begin https://www.

I have got the SSL certificate for both example.com and www.example.com from LetsEncrypt.

LetsEncrypt added the following (in my port 80 vHost):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

However this only redirects `http` to `https`. It doesn't add `www` to any `non-www`. I tried copying this over to my port 443 vHost but that resulted in a redirect loop.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved? Ideally I would prefer to do this all in vHosts but don't mind if it can only be done in `htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Start with www 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]


    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the solution:

You need to keep the existing redirect conditions added by LetsEncrypt in the port 80 vHost. Then add the following to the port 443 vHost:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

So, let the port 80 vHost redirect to `https` and then in the port 443 vHost, handle the `non-www` to `www` redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before, and i fixed it in this way :
you put this on **exemple.com.conf** :

```
ServerName exemple.com
ServerAlias www.exemple.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public/
Redirect permanent / https://www.exemple.com/
```

and then :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.exemple.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =exemple.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

Then i put this on my **exemple.com-le-ssl.conf**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Hope that's help :)